# Finding the most recent thing prior to a specific event

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm doing some timestamp problem solving but am stuck with some join logic.

I have a table of data like so:

```
id, event_time, event_type, location
1001, 2018-06-04 18:23:48.526895 UTC, I, d
1001, 2018-06-04 19:26:44.359296 UTC, I, h
1001, 2018-06-05 06:07:03.658263 UTC, I, w
1001, 2018-06-07 00:47:44.651841 UTC, I, d
1001, 2018-06-07 00:48:17.857729 UTC, C, d
1001, 2018-06-08 00:04:53.086240 UTC, I, a
1001, 2018-06-12 21:23:03.071829 UTC, I, d
...
```

And I'm trying to find the timestamp difference between when a user has an event_type of `C` and the most recent event type of `I` up to event_type `C` for a given location value.

Ultimately the schema I'm after is:

```
id, location, timestamp_diff
1001, d, 33
1001, z, 21
1002, a, 55
...
```

I tried the following, which works for only one `id` value, but doesn't seem to work for multiples `id`s. I might be over-complicating the issue, but I wasn't sure. On one `id` it gives about 5 rows, which is right. However, when I open it up two `id`s, I get upwards of 200 rows when I should get something like 7 (5 for the first `id` and 2 for the second):

```
with c as (
select 
id
,event_time as c_time
,location
from data
where event_type = 'C'
and id = '1001'
)

,i as (
select 
id
,event_time as i_time
,location
from data
where event_type = 'I'
)

,check1 as (
c.*
,i.i_time
from c
left join i on (c.id = i.id and c.location = i.location)
group by 1,2,3,4
having i_time <= c_time
)

,check2 as (
select
id
,c_time
,location
,max(i_time) as i_time
from check1
group by 1,2,3
)

select
id
,location
,timestamp_diff(c_time, i_time, second) as timestamp_diff
```

Comment: can there be more than one `C` row per id?

Comment: Yes, there can be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, location, TIMESTAMP_DIFF(event_time, i_event_time, SECOND) AS diff
FROM (
  SELECT *, MAX(IF(event_type = 'I', event_time, NULL)) OVER(win2) AS i_event_time
  FROM (
    SELECT *, COUNTIF(event_type = 'C') OVER(win1) grp
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
    WINDOW win1 AS (PARTITION BY id, location ORDER BY event_time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) 
  )
  WINDOW win2 AS (PARTITION BY id, location, grp ORDER BY event_time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) 
) 
WHERE event_type = 'C' 
AND NOT i_event_time IS NULL
```

This version addresses some edge cases - like for example case when there are consecutive 'C' events with "missing" 'I' events as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1001 id, TIMESTAMP '2018-06-04 18:23:48.526895 UTC' event_time, 'I' event_type, 'd' location UNION ALL
  SELECT 1001, '2018-06-04 19:26:44.359296 UTC', 'I', 'h' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1001, '2018-06-05 06:07:03.658263 UTC', 'I', 'w' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1001, '2018-06-07 00:47:44.651841 UTC', 'I', 'd' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1001, '2018-06-07 00:48:17.857729 UTC', 'C', 'd' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1001, '2018-06-08 00:04:53.086240 UTC', 'C', 'd' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1001, '2018-06-12 21:23:03.071829 UTC', 'I', 'd' 
)
SELECT id, location, TIMESTAMP_DIFF(event_time, i_event_time, SECOND) AS diff
FROM (
  SELECT *, MAX(IF(event_type = 'I', event_time, NULL)) OVER(win2) AS i_event_time
  FROM (
    SELECT *, COUNTIF(event_type = 'C') OVER(win1) grp
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
    WINDOW win1 AS (PARTITION BY id, location ORDER BY event_time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) 
  )
  WINDOW win2 AS (PARTITION BY id, location, grp ORDER BY event_time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) 
) 
WHERE event_type = 'C' 
AND NOT i_event_time IS NULL
```

result is

```
Row id      location    diff     
1   1001    d           33
```

while if not to address that mentioned edge case it would be

```
Row id      location    diff     
1   1001    d           33   
2   1001    d           83795
```

Comment: Hmm this seems to work for the most part but is giving me a lot of results where the time difference is over 100,000 seconds. When I check the data for those cases, the actual difference between 'C' and 'I' events is more on the seconds range.

Comment: @AI52487963 - interesting, if you could provide few examples of such entries - i can check what is going on

Comment: Actually on further inspection that's just a quirk of the data. There really is that much time in some cases! Crazy! Otherwise the code you provided works great, thanks.

Comment: really appreciate your follow-up and clearing this :o)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cumulative `max()` function to get the most recent `i` time before every event.

Then just filter based on the `C` event:

```
select id, location,
       timestamp_diff(event_time, i_event_time, second) as diff
from (select t.*,
             max(case when event_type = 'I' then event_time end) over (partition by id, location order by event_time) as i_event_time
      from t
     ) t
where event_type = 'C';
```

Comment: also you should add `location` to `partition by` :o)

Comment: agree, it is not clear from question  - but I think OP will be able to finalize the stuff based on your answer and maybe my answer also will make sense to OP :o)